# Angular Material placeholder on input doesnt flow

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material 6.4.5 and I have problem with floating my placeholder.

this is my html

```
<mat-form-field class='search'>
   <input matInput placeholder='Search' value='book' [(ngModel)]='search'>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image]

I also have problem with my mat-select it doesn't open

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-select placeholder="Test">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let foo of test" [value]="foo.id">{{foo.lastName}}</mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Is there any idea what wrong, I tried whole afternoon and with no success.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `title` instead of `placeholder`.

Comment: Most likely you haven't properly imported the Material modules into your root module.

Answer (score 0):

Property `name` is mandatory for input element with `[(ngModel)]`

```
<mat-form-field class='search'>
   <input matInput placeholder='Search' name="search" value='book' [(ngModel)]='search'>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

I forget to import theme in my styles.css.  Everything works now